# visNetwork geographical coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, igraph, network-analysis

I'm trying to plot a geographic igraph network using visNetwork.
The igraph code is below, I've found this visNetwork solution, but I'm having problems adapting the code correctly https://github.com/DataKnowledge/visNetwork/blob/master/R/visIgraphLayout.R

```
library(raster)
library(igraph)
greece <- getData('GADM', country='GRC', level=1)
df<-data.frame("from" = c("Athens", "Iraklio", "Thessaloniki", "Patra"), "to"= c("Thessaloniki", "Thessaloniki", "Athens", "Iraklio"))
meta <- data.frame("name"=c("Athens", "Iraklio", "Thessaloniki", "Patra"), 
           "lon"=c(23.72800,25.13356,22.94090,21.73507),  
           "lat"=c(37.98415,35.33349,40.63229,38.24628))
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=T, vertices=meta)
lo <- as.matrix(meta[,2:3])
plot(greece)
plot(g, layout=lo, add = TRUE, rescale = FALSE)
```

**edit**
**Update**

I have a R-igraph network, this is visualised using the visNetwork library.
I have a spatial data frame, this is visualised using Leaflet.
How do I visualise the network on a map but keeping the visNetwork functionality? See [example here](http://www.singlegrave.nl/network/index.html)